# Why does ElasticSearch only return 5 buckets for dat_histogram aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index full of legacy log data that I want to bucket by hour to get an idea of when the most active times were for the data. The date_histogram aggregation seemed like it would be perfect for this, but I'm having a problem figuring out how to get the aggregation to make more than 5 buckets.

The index has about 725 million documents in it, spanning about 7 or 8 months so that should be several thousand buckets by hour but when I use the following query body I only get back 5 buckets

```
{
    "query":{
        "match_all":{}
    },
    "aggs":{
        "events_per_hour":{
            "date_histogram":{
                "field":"timestamp",
                "interval":"hour"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the results seem to span about the right time period, but it forces it into 5 buckets instead of the several thousand I was expecting

```
{
    "took": 276509,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 726450222,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "events_per_hour": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "1970-01-18T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1515600000,
                    "doc_count": 51812791
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "1970-01-18T14:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1519200000,
                    "doc_count": 130819007
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "1970-01-18T15:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1522800000,
                    "doc_count": 188046057
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "1970-01-18T16:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1526400000,
                    "doc_count": 296038311
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "1970-01-18T17:00:00.000Z",
                    "key": 1530000000,
                    "doc_count": 59734056
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to google for the issue, but it looks like the size parameter that you can add to terms aggregations but that's not available for the histograms apparently and I tried to change the `search.max_buckets` setting but that didn't work either.

Is there any way to get ES to split this data into the thousands of buckets I need? Or do I have to write something that just downloads all of the data and splits it manually in memory?

Comment: I'm a bit surprised to see dates in 1970. Probably because your timestamps are in seconds instead of milliseconds. Can you share what you get if you add the following aggregation? `"minmaxdate": {"stats": {"field": "timestamp"}}` ?

Comment: Yeah this is definitely the issue, and we've had problems with this before when trying to use the data in Kibana

`"min_as_string": "1970-01-18T13:40:22.510Z", "max_as_string": "1970-01-18T17:13:04.798Z"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you translate the "key_as_string" (1970-01-18T13:00:00.000) from the date to epoch, you'll see:
Epoch timestamp: 1515600
Timestamp in milliseconds: 1515600000

And if you translate 1515600000 in epoch to date you'll receive right date (Wednesday, January 10, 2018 4:00:00 PM)

So, look like you send the epoch, but in the date format of the field defined milliseconds.